# Week accuracy with testing data

Tags: data-science, missing-data

I'm dealling with a data science problem, and I got this problem.

I have a labelled data (Training data) and non labelled data (Test data) and both of them have a lot of missing data.

I worked with my data and I split it to trainig data and validating data

I got a very good accuracy and a very small RMSE error between Y_validation and the predicted one ( `model.predict(X_validate)` ). But when I submit my solution, the RMSE error get bigger with testing data !

What can I do ?!

Comment: your test data should be labelled...https://towardsdatascience.com/train-validation-and-test-sets-72cb40cba9e7

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to label your test data. If your test data is not labelled, you will not be able to gauge the accuracy. It will not return accurate error representation.

You need to understand that the training set contain a known output that the model learn from. The test data have to be labelled so that when the model returns its predictions on the test data, we are able to gauge whether the model has correctly predicted the label given to the test data.

On top of doing a train test split you can also do cross validation to improve your model performance. You can understand more from here. (https://towardsdatascience.com/train-test-split-and-cross-validation-in-python-80b61beca4b6)

Answer (score 0):

This will happen sometimes when a model doesn't generalize well. This can happen when a model over fits to training data.

Resampling or better sampling of test and train data (which as mentioned, needs to be labeled) can help you get a better generalized model.